# Передача аргументов в свой профиль python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, sqlite3

```
class SQLighter:
    def __init__(self, database):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(database, check_same_thread = False)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        self.cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stats (user_id INT, user_name TEXT, survived INT, infected INT)")
    def add_user(self, id, name, survived, infected):
        #"""Добавляем значение"""
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO `stats` (user_id, user_name, survived, infected) VALUES (?,?,?,?)""", (id, name, survived, infected))
    def get_nick(self, id):
        #'''Эта функция позволяет извлекать нужное значение(в данном случае id) из таблицы stats'''
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("SELECT user_id FROM stats WHERE id = ?", (id,)).fetchall()
    def set_fast(self, id):
        #'''Эта функция позволяет устанавливать значение исходя из параметра id'''
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("UPDATE stats SET infected=X WHERE id=?", (id))
sql_lighter = SQLighter("database.db")
sql_lighter.add_user(982543922, "Вова", 1, 1)
```

Вот допустим у меня загрузились данные из бд и как их теперь передать в свой профиль, якобы сделать глобально переменные survived и infected

Comment: Что такое "свой профиль"?

Comment: типо там моя статистика: Мой профиль
Мой ID: [982543922]
Мой Псевдоним: [NoPressF]
Моё Ф.И: [Вова Ефанов]
Количество побед за выжившего: [0]
Количество заражений за заражённого: [0]
Версия помощника бота: [V0.3]
Версия игры зомби: [V0.9]

Comment: Где эта статистика? На консоли, или в графическом интерфейсе, или в веб интерфейсе, или облаками на небе?

Comment: telegram bot python

Comment: [дубль](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1280402/178576)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [TypeError: add\_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'infected'](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1280402/typeerror-add-user-missing-1-required-positional-argument-infected)